# sumif with multiple conditions

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sumifs

I have an excel sheet that tells me for each departure date of a flight how many seats I had sold in the days before, day by date. A Pick up rate, so it's called.

I can use a sumif function to sum up all the bookings that came in for a specific departure date, but how can I set the formula in order to sum up ONLY the dates that are after a specific day? On example the reservations that came in for departure date 31dec13, starting ONLY from 1dec13

Thank you!

Giovanni

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like:

```
=SUMIF(A:A,">"&41608,B:B)
```

may serve where ColumnA holds dates, ColumnB the number of seats sold and `41608` is the index number for the day before your start date.

If you have a separate column for flight number (say C) switch to multiple conditions:

```
=SUMIFS(B:B,A:A,">"&41608,C:C,"MH370")
```

where `MH370` is the relevant flight identifier.

Extend the principle if you have the same flight identifiers for departures on different dates.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a column (eventually hidden) with the complex condition (built wit ANDs, ORs, and so on).
Then you can use SUMIF with a condition on that new column.